# How to resolve system event handler error in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to clear the system event hadler in C#.

I am getting following error:

"Error  1   No overload for 'Initialize_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'   D:\Tool\Macro\Testmac\Testmac\Form1.Designer.cs 72  38  Testmac
"
when i change my function name and argument object. i am getting this error. Please guide me.

Here my code:

```html
OLD code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}


New CODE:

private void Initialize(string filename, string tablename)
        {
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO\"";
            string fieldstring = "(ID int, Field1 char(255), Field2 char(255))";

        }
```

Please guide me

Answer (score 2):

The `System.EventHandler` delegate are of type

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So this error means you have something in code like `some_handler += this.Initialize`, you should define the handler to `private void handler(object sender, EventArgs e)`, and call `Initialize` function in it.